# Remove screen saver when run program

Tags: android

I would like my application to remove Android's screen saver each time I run my application from Android studio on my phone. I have added `WAKE_LOCK` in manifest:

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I also added `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

But my application still not breaks screen saver. How to achieve that ?